# HWIOAuthBundle + FosUserBundle - custom form types

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

Is there any option to separate registration form types? I would like to have 2 form types for normal registration and oauth registration. It looks like the bundle uses fosuserbundle's form type by default and ignores `registration_form` section in the configuration. It worked fine in previous versions of hwioauthbundle. Broken after upgrade to 0.3.*@dev.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solved by overwriting bundle's alias in config:

```
services:
    hwi_oauth.registration.form.factory
        alias: my.oauth.registration.form.factory
```